# CSS animation not loaded after refresh

Tags: html, css

I'm facing some weird issue. I added css animation on some element in the page, when I open it on iOs the animation is running but if I refresh the page the animation is not running anymore. That's happens only on iOs(safari and chrome).

I tried to add animation-delay but it didn't help. The animation is set on some icon. This icon should animate on 'after' element.

```
  .icon {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    background-image: url('images/banners/bus-icon-banner-1.svg');
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate3d(60px, 64px, 0);
    top: 0;
    html[dir=ltr] & {
    left: -148px;
    }

    animation: orange-line-ani 5s cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.01, 0.15, 0.05) 2s infinite;
    @include keyframes(orange-line-ani) {
      0% {
        transform: translate3d(57px, 64px, 0);
      }
      30% {
        transform: translate3d(63px, 28px,0);
      }
      70% {
        transform: translate3d(86px, 28px,0);
      }
      100% {
        transform: translate3d(89px, -6px,0);
      }
    }
  }
```

Any help?

Comment: If you're using a CSS pre-processor, please either add the relevant tag for it, or show us the compiled CSS. Also, if would be good if you could show us a small **working** example, generally without seeing the problem the best we can do is guess.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to animate this icon on 'after' element, then you should add **::after** pseudo-element after the **.icon**. Something like this:

```css
.icon::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    background-image: url('images/banners/bus-icon-banner-1.svg');
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate3d(60px, 64px, 0);
    top: 0;
    html[dir=ltr] & {
    left: -148px;
    }

    animation: orange-line-ani 5s cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.01, 0.15, 0.05) 2s infinite;
    @include keyframes(orange-line-ani) {
      0% {
        transform: translate3d(57px, 64px, 0);
      }
      30% {
        transform: translate3d(63px, 28px,0);
      }
      70% {
        transform: translate3d(86px, 28px,0);
      }
      100% {
        transform: translate3d(89px, -6px,0);
      }
    }
  }
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, the ::after was removed by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason there is no `::after` like so?

```
 .icon::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    background-image: url('images/banners/bus-icon-banner-1.svg');
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate3d(60px, 64px, 0);
    top: 0;
    html[dir=ltr] & {
    left: -148px;
    }
```

Comment: Nope, just a mistake. Anyway, I created a div instead of adding the animation in icon::after and apply those styles to the div. Now it works. thanks!